# ssh to ec2 instance from local node shows the below error

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ssh

> [prog@prog-workstation opt]$ ssh -i "prog.pem"
>   root@ec2-3-83-75-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com The authenticity of host
>   'ec2-3-83-35-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com (3.83.35.144)' can't be
>   established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   16:cd:05:0f:a......62:27:d7:47:d6:c0. Are you sure you want to
>   continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
>   'ec2-3-83-75-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com,3.83.75.144' (RSA) to the
>   list of known hosts. Permission denied
>   (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Scenario 1: The above issue happens only with other nodes , the main node which was used at beginning for setup gives no issues during ssh.

But i created new keypair and downloaded to new node, and when i am using the same as shown above i get this error.

Scenario 2: Even if copy the original keypair from the main machine to other node and try , still i get this same issue .

Working Scenario: So i am currently working by first doing ssh to the original node --> then from there am doing ssh to ec2 (This always works)

But i want to access those ec2 from any other nodes also , as i have downloaded the key pair in other nodes also but i get the above error.

Comment: What do you mean by "original node", "other nodes" and "main node"? Are you referring to an Amazon EMR cluster? Or are these just normal Amazon EC2 instances? If you have launched an EC2 instance from the Amazon Linux AMI, then the default login user is `ec2-user` (not `root`) unless you have made any changes.

Comment: It's ec2 instance launched from AMI,  main / original node I meant the one used during initial setup. The key pair from here always works when I do ssh.   1.But when I use this same key pair in other machines to ssh it gives error.   2 also if generate new key pair to any new/other nodes for ssh, still they give the same error. @John Rotenstien

Comment: What do you mean by "generate new key pair to any new/other nodes for ssh"? Are you generating the keypair within the EC2 console, then launching the instance by specifying that keypair? Why are you logging in as `root`? Where did the AMI come from?

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Am getting this error even when am logging in as centos@ instead of root.  I had taken AMI from market place.  Here am trying to ssh to AWS EC2 instance from my local machine . so even if generate a  new  key pair by following these steps ===>   In network & security --> we can create key pair --> then save in my local machine . Then while doing ssh to EC2 instance provide this key pair .  But am getting the above ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched with a nominated Keypair, the public half of the keypair is copied to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the appropriate user (Amazon Linux = `ec2-user`, Ubuntu = `ubuntu`).

Then, when you try to login to the instance, you must specify the private half of the keypair in the `ssh` command.

The instance receiving the `ssh` request will compare the incoming keypair against the keypair already stored in that user's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file and, if they match, the session will be opened.

This behaviour is only supported by *some* AMIs, such as Amazon Linux and most of the AMIs listed in the "Quick" section of the EC2 console. This is because there is software installed that will copy the keypair on first launch.

Therefore, if you wish to use a new keypair with a Linux instance, you must launch the instance with the keypair specified. Merely creating a keypair in the console does *not* update any currently-running instances.

If you do wish to add a keypair to an instance, you will need to login to the instance, navigate to the desired user's home directory and edit the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file by appending the public half of the keypair. The user will then be permitted to login to that instance. (This method is standard Linux, not specific to Amazon EC2.)

Since you are using an AMI from the Marketplace, you will need to read the provided instructions to discover how to login to the instance.